# Pinterest Bookmarklet Not Finding Images

Tags: wordpress, pinterest

I have searched quite a bit for a solution and can't seem to find anything on this topic so I thought I would reach out to this amazing community.

I will try to provide enough context here so that others may be able to see what is going wrong.

Up till a few days ago I have been able to use the standard pinterest bookmarklet to pin images from my blog's main page ([Forged Photography](http://www.forgedphotography.com)) to pinterest. I tried pinning some images today and realized that it is only finding my header image and none of the other content.

It is a wordpress blog and I have deactivated my plugins and changed my theme to eliminate those aspects as a cause and the behavior still remains.

I have uploaded content in two ways:

- Uploaded photos via Wordpress and created galleries

  - Pinterest bookmarklet only finds the header image and the featured gallery image
- Embedding images that are hosted on facebook

  - I can still pin them if I click on individual pictures but I can't pin from the main page of the blog.
  - When I used to click the bookmarklet from the main page of my blog it used to pull up all of the images contained in all of the posts and enable me to pin them, now it only finds my header image.

Any ideas on what may have happened or what is preventing the bookmarklet from finding the images?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it isn't the answer that I was looking for but it seems to work out. A nice lady reached out to me on Facebook who was experiencing the same issue, turns out Pinterest won't find images that are under 200px...

Doesn't explain why I was able to pin them in the past but now I can't. I am not crazy about the way the thumbnails look @ 200px, any other ideas on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img src="smallimage.jpg" data-pin-media="largeimage.jpg" />
```

The bookmarklet should pick up the image you send in `data-pin-media`.  Also worth trying out: `data-pin-url`, which will make the bookmarklet pin the URL you suggest rather than the URL of the page you're on right now.

Comment: I have a strange issue where I'm using data-pin-media (to detect/pin the full image) but Pinterest only detects the full image 30% of the time :-/